# Can you find the killer?

Tags: cipher, mystery

Mystery Cipher:

> Rakesh murdered in his office. CID arrested four suspects.
>
> 1. Mehul Patel - Business partner
> 2. Reena - His wife
> 3. Ekta - His Secretary
> 4. Chirag - His Servant
>
> All these people visited Rakesh on the day of his murder for various
>   reason as they told to CID.
>
> CID found a note on the table. "**1aeddaa339fa082c61fa936c4165d398**" was 
>   written on it.

CID breaks the code and found the culprit. Can you?

Comment: I am downvoting this question because this is a simple, straightforward puzzle that does not [bring anything novel](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1719/19447). Also, I fail to see how this kind of note may have appeared at the crime scene at all, in-universe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suspect is :

> Ekta

because :

> **1aeddaa339fa082c61fa936c4165d398** is Ekta encoded with [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).

Comment: you  have a list of cipher that you check or you knew it was MD5?

Comment: @lois6b Stumbled across [this puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10479/six-series-six-words) two or three days ago, and so MD5 was the first thing that came to my mind when seeing this new puzzle.

Comment: just FYI, if you search for `1aeddaa339fa082c61fa936c4165d398` directly on Google it says you the answer -.-

Comment: Nice catch @MiquelColl, I did that in two steps by searching "md5 decoder" first haha :)

Comment: Instead of writing this code "1aeddaa339fa082c61fa936c4165d398" why can't he just write "Ekta" ... just 4 words...

Answer (score 0):

Murderer is

> Mehul Patel

He tried to frame

> Ekta

Because

> Ekta was learning MD5 while this event happened and Mehul tried to make CID believe it was one of Ekta's draft papers. Where "Ekta" encoded by MD5 is "1aeddaa339fa082c61fa936c4165d398"

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! What in the question makes you believe that this is correct?

Comment: @Deusovi does this look better overlord. Let me be at your disposal.

Comment: Ha, I appreciate the "overlord". But the issue was not with that part (after all, that was already given by IAmInPLS) but with the evidence of the framing.

Comment: I refuse to believe someone would leave his/her name on the table at a crime scene.